# pcap stream rotation and pruning

Tags: logging, tcpdump, pcap, rotation

Some of my servers collect a lot of packet data.  Is there a utility (or patch to `tcpdump(1)`) to log a pcap stream to disk which:

1. Rotates based on size of data written
2. Prunes written files, keeping only the *N* most recent
3. Does not re-use output filenames
4. Is self-contained
   (Ruling out, e.g., a rotation with external pruning via `crond(8)`+`tmpwatch(8)`)

Basically I want a [`multilog`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html) or [`svlogd`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html) that groks the pcap record format.

The *-W filecount* option of `tcpdump-4.0.0` "prunes" by recycling old filenames, which violates #3 above, forcing me to consult mtimes to determine recency and providing no guarantees against surprise truncation of the log file.

The *-G* option introduces `strftime(2)`-specifier support in output filenames, which would give me at least second-precision in file names, but I can't figure out how to get pruning to work with this scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dumpcap](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html) should do what you need.

```
dumpcap -w /tmp/output.pcap -b filesize:20000 -b files:10
```

will rotate through a maximum of 10 files with a maximum size of 20 MB. Each file has a unique name, e.g. output_00018_20100315122857.pcap.

[Daemonlogger](http://www.snort.org/users/roesch/Site/Daemonlogger/Daemonlogger.html) should work as well, but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want [Grok](http://gitorious.org/grok).  It does what you want and then some.

Comment: Thanks, Bill.  For posterity, can you be more specific, say, assuming an input of "tcpdump ... -w -" ?
At first blush, `grok` (the utility) is a web interface, and its cousin `bag` has an incomplete man page that leaves me guessing how this might address my needs.

Comment: `bag` will capture packets (using `libpcap`) and store them in a few formats: indexes, raw pcap, etc.  It rotates files out intelligently based on an amount of files or time, as you configure it.

The `grok` frontend gives you a nice way to search those indexes and pcaps.  It's optional, but nice.

The documentation sucks, but you can probably email the devs and ask questions.  They're nice guys.